# Bit-bucket pipeline for selenium tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Does someone have any example of bitbucket.yaml which allow to run selenium tests on a pipeline please ?

integarte selenium tests on bitbucket

Comment: script are coded with python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.